# Effective design of a rules engine to avoid multiple if else loops

Tags: java

I have to determine if a package can be delivered based on rules as follows...

1. If packageWeight > 70 and below 100
   AND
2. If destinationState is in the special list of allowed state {MA, PA, NY, NJ, LA,....}
   AND
3. contentType is any of the following {ACD, FDY, PRZ, QUO, ..... }
   AND
4. CarrierName is any of the following {FXD, USPS....}

if the above conditions are true then  we can deliver the package

and in addition there are 3 flags with 15x16x8 possibilities?

what is the best way to avoid a if else cluster ?

hash map?
any other suggestions ?

Comment: Why do you think a `HashMap` is appropriate?

Comment: A `HashSet` (not a `HashMap`) is a good choice for _each_ of the three tests that test strings.  You'd set up three `HashSets` (for rule #2, #3, and #4) containing all the allowed states, content types, etc., and then use `contains` on each one.  Other than that, you're still going to have an `if` statement with several conditions.  As far as the "3 flags", we don't have enough info about what you plan to do with them.

Answer (score 4):

You can break down different group of conditions in different functions. For. e.g. Define a function `isCarrierSupported` that returns true if carrier is one of FXD, USPS etc. Similarly you can define multiple functions like `isWeightCorrect` etc. Then later in main program, you can just call these functions and get final result.

This does not avoid `if`s and `else`s but neatly organizes the program to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

#### What are looking for a is a rules engine, then just use one that already exists.

This isn't a trivial domain to be trying to create something from scratch. Just like you should not be writing your own caching system or your own ORM or your own threading framework.

Don't make the mistake of rolling your own it will end in tears.

Since you are using Java, go look at [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-expert.html). Save yourself and your company a bunch of money and use something that is already built for you.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap would work or You could convert whole flag-state into 11-bit mask (15-4 bits, 16 - 4 bits, 8 - 3 bits, or leave more bits for further growth) and use true/false array by 11-bit index.

The downside is - You'll anyway have to code same if/else logic to fill the map/array or to define a constant describing all deliver (or don't-deliver) states.

P.S. switch/case looks more appropriate then if/else here...